# jQuery remove duplicated element

Tags: jquery

What if dom generates duplicated same elements? for example:

```
    <ul id="listitem">
     <li>item1</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="listitem">
     <li>item1</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="listitem">
     <li>item1</li>
    </ul>

...
```

Then is this possible to keep one of them and delete extra  two?

Comment: ID should be unique, in case if this getting rendered by external code and you don't have control then your only choice is to iterate over all ul and remove ul that are duplicates.

Comment: Having elements with the same `id` is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ID should be unique, in case if this getting rendered by external code and you don't have control over it then your only choice is to iterate over all ul and remove ul that are duplicates.

```
var duplicateChk = {};

$('ul[id]').each (function () {
    if (duplicateChk.hasOwnProperty(this.id)) {
       $(this).remove();
    } else {
       duplicateChk[this.id] = 'true';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `id` field in HTML must be unique.  If you ever have a case where it should be applied to more than one element then a `class` is more appropriate.

```
<ul class="listitem">
  <li>item1</li>
</ul>
```

Assuming you made the switch to class you could then use the following code to remove all but the first occurance

```
$('.listitem:gt(0)').remove();
```

The `:gt(0)` portion of the selector will cause it to only match the items with index greater than 0 (everything but the first element)