# jQuery select first object from same class name

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

there are some lists that has same classes.
I want to show the first element from the lists

```
<ul class="datas">
    <li class="data-smh1">abc</li>
    <li class="data-smh1">dd</li>
    <li class="data-smh1">cc</li>
    <li class="data-sc33">abc</li>
    <li class="data-sc33">dd</li>
    <li class="data-nn61">abc</li>
    <li class="data-nn61">dd</li>
</ul>
```

result:

```
<ul class="datas">
    <li class="data-smh1">abc</li>
    <li class="data-sc33">abc</li>
    <li class="data-nn61">abc</li>
</ul>
```

I tried **$('class[name^="data-"]'**, but I couldn`t find any solutions.
Any help, thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558923/jquery-remove-duplicated-element  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822962/jquery-remove-duplicate-elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$(function(){
    $('.datas').children().each(function(i, v){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.siblings('.' + $this.attr('class')).remove()
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f9a8V/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="datas">
    <li class="data-smh1">abc</li>
    <li class="data-smh1">dd</li>
    <li class="data-smh1">cc</li>
    <li class="data-sc33">abc</li>
    <li class="data-sc33">dd</li>
    <li class="data-nn61">abc</li>
    <li class="data-nn61">dd</li>
</ul>
```

[JQUERY](http://jsfiddle.net/GwQhS/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var seen = {};
    $('.datas li').each(function(){
    //alert($(this).text());
    var txt = $(this).attr('class');
     if (seen[txt])
        $(this).remove();
    else
        seen[txt] = true;

    })
  });
```

result

```
<ul class="datas">
    <li class="data-smh1">abc</li>


    <li class="data-sc33">abc</li>

    <li class="data-nn61">abc</li>

</ul>
```

[JSFILDDEL LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/GwQhS/1/)

Comment: You copied http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822962/jquery-remove-duplicate-elements

Comment: i just use that logic but that is for duplicate element and this is for duplicate class name .. because all elements are same in result and one more thing i posted that link first in comment, after that i  make this solution in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var curr_class = '';
    var ctr = 0;    

    $('.datas li').each(function(){
        if (curr_class !== $(this).prop('class')){
            curr_class = $(this).prop('class');
            ctr = 0;
        }
        if (ctr !== 0 ){
            $(this).remove();
        }
        ++ctr;
    });

});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hBawt/1/)